# Why is my intent not starting an activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

My code is this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,"example @example. Com");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Grannylaunch Support Needed:" + System.currentTimeMillis());
startActivity(i);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Emailing Support....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
```

My problem is the intent isnt starting an activity. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

I have tried settting intent = Intent.ActionSend instead but doesnt work.

**EDIT -**

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,"example@example.com");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Grannylaunch Support Needed:" + System.currentTimeMillis());
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"");
startActivity(i);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Emailing Support....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
```

This doesn't work either.

Comment: What do you mean it does not start the activity? Are there any errors, whats in the logcat?

Comment: No and I havent checked.

Comment: Then without any more information it is going to be very hard to help you, please check the logcat and provide relevant information!

Comment: I can't seem to see anything...

Comment: If that is your real email address then please remove it as you might get a lot of spam if you dont.

Comment: Ok i will do. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
protected void sendEmail() {
      Log.i("Send email", "");

      String[] TO = {"amrood.admin@gmail.com"};
      String[] CC = {"mcmohd@gmail.com"};
      Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
      emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
      emailIntent.setType("text/plain");


      emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO);
      emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, CC);
      emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Your subject");
      emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Email message goes here");

      try {
         startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
         finish();
         Log.i("Finished sending email...", "");
      } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
         "There is no email client installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
```

> Try This It might Help U

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure an email account in your default Email application.

```
 Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    email.setType("plain/text");
                    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                            new String[] { abc@gmail.com) });
                    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
                    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"");
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email,
                            "Choose an Email client :"));
```

Comment: got more than one yet it doesnt display a list

Comment: I have more than one email app and intent doesnt show a list of them

Answer (score 0):

### Try this code :

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{strEmail});
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"subject");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

Comment: That's what i have got

Comment: Then what's the issue.? This code not working for you ?

Comment: No although i have got extra text

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    intent.setType("plain/text");
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]
                    { RECEIVER_EMIAL_ID });
                    // intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
                    // intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "mail body");
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose mail client"));
```